# how to extract column of data using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to write c# code to extract columns of data. my data looks like

[image]

what should be the regular expression if i want to extract "everything" "under" a column header for example "COMMAND" or "PID".

Comment: just split and grab..

Comment: but than i have to write the code to go line bu line and split on tab inst it ?

Comment: Looks like _column_ has spaces, so if you expect spaces in the columns, you couldn't rely on _split_. Probably the best way is to use known column lengths (if fixed) or separate by allowing only known forms for each column.

Comment: Hmm looks like that. I was trying to avoid line by line splitting and all. But i got your point.

Comment: You would have to parse line by line, no matter what you do. Also, you can limit the split to 4 times (5 columns) if you don't expect spaces in the first 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regular expression.  String Split method will work.  Try code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TT", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("STAT", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("TIME", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("COMMAND", typeof(string));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            int lineCount = 0;
            string inputLine = "";

            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine) != null)
            {
                if (++lineCount > 2)
                {
                    string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        int.Parse(inputArray[0]),
                        inputArray[1],
                        inputArray[2],
                        DateTime.Parse(inputArray[3]),
                        inputArray[4]
                    });
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i understand this. but this was something was trying to avoid. i was thinking if something like a regex says give me every thing that is below a given string.

Comment: What is wrong with the method.  Why avoid the proper way of parsing text data.  Regex give you string data and not Dates and Integers.  And doesn't create arrays.  Code above gives Dates, Integers, and arrays.